# white screen on touch for lower resolution phones after building using --prod flag

Tags: android, sass, ionic2, ionic3

This code has been working in ionic 2, however after upgrading to ionic 3 my login & signup screen have began to act weird.The entire screen goes white on input focus and also when i click any button.
The code works well in a browser however after in build production app and test on android device it acts as below.

I have tried changing the html and sass with no success and i've run out of ideas on how to fix it. Here is my login screen code if it helps.

**ionic info**

```
cli packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.6.0 (/root/Templates/Akorion Projects/EzyExtensionV2/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils)
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.6.0 (/root/Templates/Akorion Projects/EzyExtensionV2/node_modules/ionic)

global packages:

    Cordova CLI : 7.0.1 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts              : 2.0.2
    @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.1
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.2
    Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3
    Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.5.3

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.0.2
    Node              : v7.4.0
    OS                : Linux 4.9
    npm               : 5.0.0
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "EzyExtensionV2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^4.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/call-number": "^4.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^4.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/google-analytics": "^4.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^4.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^4.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/printer": "^4.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/screenshot": "^4.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^4.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^4.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/transfer": "^3.14.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.14",
    "@types/pouchdb": "6.1.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.5.3",
    "ionic-image-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "pouchdb": "^6.3.4",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.0.2",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.4.1",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.3.2",
    "ionic": "3.6.0",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

After further trials i also uncovered that it only happens when i build using the --prod flag and on android phones with resolution 480x800 and below.
I have opened up an [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12623) on the ionic github page.

Comment: Can you show `package.json` file?

Comment: It seems your problem is on your platform.Remove it and try it again.

Comment: ok let me try that

Comment: still no difference

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: No console errors

Comment: Your `ts` file's code?

Comment: app.component or login.ts

Comment: It is better if you can put both.

Comment: So i have experimented with other phones & pages and it seems to happen on lower resolution phones and it happens on all pages so long as anything is touched the entire screen goes white

Comment: I think you have to put this on Ionic's repo with a minimal working example.Hope they'll give a solution for you. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues

Comment: Please Debug your Application. You can do it with an Android Emulator which you get from Android Studio. Set the Resolution of the Android Emulator to low and then after your App did start on your Emulator go with CMD to Android Platform-Tools Folder in your Android SDK Folder on your PC and start "adb start-server" and after that type "adb logcat". Now you have full output of your Device including Errors which arent thrown on Browser.